# Points returning to the player

Tags: lua, roblox, luau

I was making a game, with a status system that includes some points to give away. I used roblox's DataStore service, but I'm having a problem with my game. After a player spends his points, distributing them in the stats he wants, after he leaves the game and re-enters those same points back to him with the same value, this can cause a point doubling glitch, which makes the unfair game, which I don't want. I think there is an error in my code, what can I do to fix it?

Code below:

```
local DataStoreService = game:GetService("DataStoreService")
local DataStore = DataStoreService:GetDataStore("PlrData")

local RunService = game:GetService("RunService")

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(Plr)
    local data = Instance.new("Folder", Plr)
    data.Name = "Data"
    
    local exp = Instance.new("IntValue", data)
    exp.Name = "Exp"
    exp.Value = 1
    
    local levels = Instance.new("IntValue", data)
    levels.Name = "Level"
    levels.Value = 1
    
    local Points = Instance.new("IntValue", data)
    Points.Name = "Points"
    Points.Value = 3
    
    
    local expneed = Instance.new("IntValue", data)
    expneed.Name = "ExpNeeded"
    expneed.Value = 100
    
    local strenght = Instance.new("IntValue", data)
    strenght.Value = 1
    strenght.Name = "Strenght"
    
    local Health = Instance.new("IntValue", data)
    Health.Value = 100
    Health.Name = "Health"
    
    local char = Plr.Character or Plr.CharacterAdded:Wait()
    local charhealth = char.Humanoid.Health
    
    local DF = Instance.new("IntValue", data)
    DF.Value = 1
    DF.Name = "DF"
    
    local PlayerId = Plr.UserId
    local PlayerData = DataStore:GetAsync(PlayerId)
    
    
    if PlayerData then
        strenght.Value = PlayerData["Strenght"]
        Health.Value = PlayerData["Health"]
        DF.Value = PlayerData["DF"]
        exp.Value = PlayerData["Exp"]
        levels.Value = PlayerData["Level"]
        expneed.Value = PlayerData["ExpNeeded"]
        Points.Value = PlayerData["Points"]
        charhealth = PlayerData["Health"]
    end
end)

local function tab(Player)
    local PlrStats = {}
    for _, v in pairs(Player.Data:GetChildren()) do 
        PlrStats[v.Name] = v.Value
    end
    return PlrStats
end


game.Players.PlayerRemoving:Connect(function(Plr) 
    local PlrStats = tab(Plr)
    local Sucess, Result = pcall(function()
        local PlrId = Plr.UserId
        DataStore:SetAsync(PlrId, PlrStats)
    end)
    if not Sucess then
        print(Result)
        warn("Error save")
    end
end)

game:BindToClose(function()
    for _, Player in pairs(game.Players:GetPlayers()) do
        task.wait()
        local PlrStats = tab(Player)
        local Sucess, Result = pcall(function()
            local PlrId = Player.UserId
            DataStore:SetAsync(PlrId, PlrStats) 
        end)
        if not Sucess then
            print(Result)
            warn("Error")
        end
    end
end)

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(Player)
    task.wait(0.1)
    local Level = Player.Data.Level
    local Exp = Player.Data.Exp
    local ExpNeed = Player.Data.ExpNeeded
    local Points = Player.Data.Points
    local Strenght = Player.Data.Strenght
    local Health = Player.Data.Health
    local DF = Player.Data:WaitForChild("DF")
    
    RunService.Heartbeat:Connect(function()
        if Exp.Value == 0 and ExpNeed.Value == 0 then
            Exp.Value = 1
            ExpNeed.Value = 100
        end
        if Points.Value > 300 then
            Points.Value = 300
        end
        if Exp.Value >= ExpNeed.Value then
            Exp.Value = Exp.Value - ExpNeed.Value
            Level.Value += 1
            ExpNeed.Value *= 1.13
            Points.Value += 3
        end
        if Strenght.Value == 0 or DF.Value == 0 or Health.Value == 0 then
            Strenght.Value = 1
            DF.Value = 1
            Health.Value = 1
        end
        if Strenght.Value > 100 or DF.Value > 100 then
            Strenght.Value = 100
            DF.Value = 100
        end
        if Health.Value > 1000 then
            Health.Value = 1000
        end
    end)
    
    RunService.Heartbeat:Connect(function()
        if Level.Value >= 100 then
            Level.Value = 100
        end
    end)
end)
```

Comment: How does the glitch happen? How often does it happen? Elaborate

Comment: Well, i enter the game and the points i spended returns to me. Example, i have 6 points, i spend that 6 points. Then i leave the game. This 6 points returns again to me and i can spend them again.